# Saved Upload File in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I found some problem regarding saved file upload in codeigniter, i already got some advice from internet, but after i implemented it doesn't worked, let's check this out :

Controller :

```
function save_data()
                {           
                    $in['jenis'] = $this->input->post("jenis");
                    $in['judul'] = $this->input->post("judul");
                    $in['nomor'] = $this->input->post("nomor");
                    $in['tanggal'] = $this->input->post("tanggal");
                    $in['nilai'] = $this->input->post("nilai");
                    $in['deskripsi'] = $this->input->post("deskripsi");
                    $in['penerbit'] = $this->input->post("penerbit");
                    $acak=rand(00000000000,99999999999);
                    $bersih=$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                    $nm=str_replace(" ","_","$bersih");
                    $pisah=explode(".",$nm);
                    $nama_murni=$pisah[0];
                    $ubah=$acak.$nama_murni; //tanpa ekstensi
                    $config["file_name"]=$ubah; //dengan eekstensi
                    $in["lampiran"]=$acak.$nm;
                    $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'exe|sql|psd|pdf|xls|ppt|php|php4|php3|js|swf|Xhtml|zip|wav|bmp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|html|htm|txt|rtf|mpeg|mpg|avi|doc|docx|xlsx';
                    $config['max_size'] = '50000';
                    $config['max_width'] = '1200';
                    $config['max_height'] = '1200';                     
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                    if(!$this->upload->do_upload())
                    {
                     echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                    }
                    else {
                    $this->db->insert("tbl_pengadaan",$in);
                    ?>
                        <script>
                            window.parent.location.reload(true);
                        </script>
                    <?php
                    }
                }
```

Views (Lampiran's Form) :

```
        <label class="control-label" for="nama_hukuman">File Lampiran</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="file" name="userfile">
        </div>
```

after i ran my code above, it shown warning like this :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: userfile

Filename: controllers/dashboard_admin.php

Line Number: 279
```

file attachment can't uploaded and what i want is after uploading the file, file names automatically saved with unique number in database sql, for make user download list..

*if there any advice, please,
thanks..*

Comment: First check to make sure the file actually uploaded successfully.

Comment: @RobertRocha file can't uploaded because warning above

Comment: did you added  enctype=multipart/form-data in the form(view side) and can you also share the results of $_FILES , like var_dump($_FILES);

Comment: Can you share your complete view including the <form> tag. Thanks!

Comment: @chad already solved with LogicBlower's comment, (: